# How to approach the following query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to approach the following query in oracle sql

```
select last_trans_date,
last_trans_date<sysdate-180 as "a",
last_trans_date<sysdate-360 as "b"
from x;
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how to select col1, col1>sysdate-180 as col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
select last_trans_date,
       CASE
         WHEN last_trans_date < sysdate-180 THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO'
       END as "a",
       CASE
         WHEN last_trans_date < sysdate-360 THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO'
       END as "b"
  from x;
```

The Oracle database doesn't support a BOOLEAN type so you can't return the result of the comparison directly. Here I've arbitrarily chosen to return 'YES' and 'NO' - change it to whatever you like better/best.

Comment: thanks for replying Bob but i need the data based upon the condition like for the column alias "a" i need the data based on the condition ast_trans_date < sysdate-180.

Comment: What data is it that you need? In other words, if LAST_TRANS_DATE < SYSDATE - 180, what value do you want to show up in column "a" in the result set?